# replace the window blind with one piece broken

Tags: windows, blinds

one piece of window blind is broken. Please see the attached image. The rental office asked me to replace the whole by myself or pay the full cost for them to replace. I am not sure is that possible to just replace that small piece or has to replace the whole blind. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If the other section was till in place, might be possible to glue/attach it back.  Without it there, you need to worry about all those strings and knots, which would be a big pain to undo and redo.

Comment: Unfortunately the rental office already knows, so gluing it together will not pass.

Comment: That looks like one of those lessons everyone learns eventually - "Don't open the window by reaching through the blind." That works every single time… except the last one. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blinds appear to be thick wood slats. If they are, and you have the broken piece(s) it may be possible to carefully glue the pieces back together. Whether the rental office will accept the repair is up to them.

Alternatively, you could unstring the pull strings and stack up the existing slats without the gap, then restring the pull strings.

Either method is possible but are a lot of work. And time is money.

You're probably looking at replacing with a new set.

Comment: Unstring, wow, it is a murder

Comment: Gluing *might* work, but as we can see three vertical strings 'sans slat' then it has to be broken into at least 4 pieces… otherwise the string would have prevented its removal. Re-stringing & moving every lower slat up a slot.. hmmm… rather you than me. ;)

Comment: D'oh! Not thinking - of course, you'd only have to steal the bottom slat & move it into the empty space <facepalm> You'd still be facing the re-string though. Not fun.